# How to recall or review WEA Alerts e.g. Amber Alerts?

Tags: notifications, alerts, weather

The Wireless Emergency Alert (WEA) system sends warnings for weather and other emergencies. On my AT&T Moto X, the alert is a super loud sound and an alert box with an OK button. Once you push OK, the alert vanishes. Is there any way to recall it and see the alert text again? On iOS, WEA alerts are visible in the usual notifications pane. That doesn't seem to be the case for Android. Does anyone know if there are plans to fix this?

I imagine most people push OK in a panic to stop the loud sound, and then are left wondering what it was exactly that was so important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Oreo (8.1)... Settings -> Apps & notifications -> Advanced -> Emergency alerts -> Emergency alert history.

In 8.0, it might be called "Mobile broadcast settings" instead.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

in Oreo 8.1.0

settings --> network & internet --> wireless emergency alerts

Answer (score 1):

There should be and app on the phone called Emergency Alerts with a red triangle and a white background that will let you view the active emergency alerts in your area.

Answer (score 0):

Try Settings > Connections > More connection settings > Emergency alerts.

Answer (score 0):

On my device, they are hidden in a different place. Navigate to:

*Settings › Sounds and Vibration › more sound settings › Emergencey Alerts › Emergency Alert History*

Answer (score 0):

I use an Android phone and had the same reaction you experienced.  I made several attempts to get info via some emergency info links I'd saved to my home screen to no avail. .BUT I found the alert story by visiting a local TV news website like bay area abc7news.com, where a red Breaking News banner appears at the top of the page. I clicked on Amber Alert link & it took me to the story & details.